# HTML Select Element appears empty on Chrome in Mobile

Tags: html, google-chrome, responsive

I am using a regular html select field with various options. But it seems to be empty on Mobile with the Chrome Browser. Firefox and other Browsers are showing it as expected. It shows the options after tapping on the empty field. But I doubt this is how it's meant to look on Chrome. Am I missing something here? Is there a workaround? I couldn't find the issue or a solution to this.

```
<select size="5" id="info2" name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
  <option value="#">Vespa P 80 X 80 ccm V8X1T 1981 - 1996 </option>
</select>
```

[image: Before the tap]

[image: After the tap]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with size attribute.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. The `<select>` was working fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it appeared empty on page load. If I clicked on it, I could still see the options in the dropdown.

I had applied `line-height: 0` to fix a padding issue in Firefox, which turned out to cause the issue explained above in Chrome. I fixed it by switching it to `line-height: 1`.